# post data and get back response in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to post a data to a website and get the response back from the server. This is the code that i am using:

```
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.indianrail.gov.in/train_Schedule.html");
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0";
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    string postData = lccp_trnname.Text;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Response.Write(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Response.Write(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException ee)
    {
        Label1.Text = ee.Message;

    }
```

instead of getting the reply back from the server, i am getting redirected to the same webpage in which i am posting the data. Plz help me if anyone has got any idea as what has gone wrong with my code. i've been trying since long back but all efforts went in vain. So plz help

Comment: Without knowing more about the page you're posting to, there's little chance anyone will be able to help you.  Can you post any details about that page?  Are you sure it's expecting a POST and not a GET?  Is it requiring certain fields to be present?  Are there anti-bot techniques employed?

Comment: actually i tried to post data using this simple html code, it worked. This is the code:<html>
 <head><title>Sample HTML form</title></head>
 <body>
 <form name="trn_num" method="post" action="http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_trnnum_cgi.cgi">
 <input type="text" name="lccp_trnname" id="lccp_trnname" />
 <input type="submit" name="getIt" value="Get Schedule" />
 </form>
 </body></html> . So the page is expecting a POST and it only requires one input. i don't think there are anti-bot techniques involved.

Answer (score 2):

You must post data to http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_trnnum_cgi.cgi instead of http://www.indianrail.gov.in/train_Schedule.html

**UPDATE:**

The second problem is that you are not sending name of "lccp_trnname" parameter in data. This will make it work:

```
string postData = "lccp_trnname=" + lccp_trnname.Text;
```

Comment: i tried to post the data to http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_trnnum_cgi.cgi but in that case i am getting the response as "access violation" as it is a cgi page. The cgi page is actually taking the data from http://www.indianrail.gov.in/train_Schedule.html and is running a query on its database and then it is showing the result.